# Unexpected behavior of linux specific getline() function in C

Tags: c, glibc, stdio

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 1024

void reverse(FILE *, FILE *);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  ...
  reverse(fptr, stdout);
  ...

  return 0;
}

void reverse(FILE * instream, FILE * outstream)
{
  char ** buf;
  char * lbuf;
  int counter, i;
  size_t slen;

  counter = 0;

  buf = malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char));
  if (buf == NULL)
  {
    fputs("malloc failed\n", stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  lbuf = NULL;
  while ((counter < MAXLEN) && (getline(&lbuf, &slen, instream) != -1))
  {
    buf[counter] = lbuf;
    counter++;
    lbuf = NULL;
  }


  for (i = counter - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    fputs(buf[i], outstream);
    free(buf[i]);
  }

  free(buf);
}
```

I have written this function to print a file in reverse order like

```
Hello World
How are you ?
what are you doing ?
```

output should look like this

```
what are you doing ?
How are you ?
Hello World
```

But there is unexpected behavior. I am using Linux specific `stdio` function `getline()` to scan arbitrary long line.
The problem is that if the value of `MAXLEN` is 4, 5, 6, ... like this the program is giving `double free or corrupt address error abort()` particularly the `free()` function while printing the output.

I looked into the address returned by the `geline()` function it seems that
after like 4 iterations the address of the first buffer returned by the `getline()` is getting corrupted. If the `MAXLEN` is 2 or big enough like 1024 the problem doesn't happen.

**Sample input** which I took

```
When to the sessions of sweet silent thought
I summon up remembrance  of things past,
I sigh the lack of many a thing I sought,
And with old woes new wail my dear time's waste:
Then can I drown an eye, unused to flow,
For precious friends hid in death's dateless night
And weep afresh love's long since cancell's woe,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `char ** buf;`, the type of `buf` is `pointer to char*`, where you are allocating space for an array of `char*`.

```
buf = malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char));
```

This only allocates space for MAXLEN chars, not MAXLEN pointers (each of which is 8 bytes on a 64-bit CPU). So you later over-run the space allocated, and entries get corrupted (they overlap with `buf[counter]`).

The correct allocation is: `buf = malloc (MAXLEN * sizeof(char *));`

Typically I would prefer to allocate according to the type of the pointer being returned:

```
buf = malloc (MAXLEN * sizeof(*buf));
```

i.e. "allocate space for MAXLEN items of the things `buf` points to". This avoids errors introduced when the type of `buf` is altered.

`getline()` is not part of the problem: you just store the pointers it returns in an array too small for them. The reason your code works for small data sets is that `malloc()` rounds up allocations to 16 or 32 bytes to maintain alignment of objects (both for its own free-list, and so the compiler can make reasonable assumptions about the alignment of user structures).

So (typically) your first two data lines are OK, the next two damage the hidden header for the next line (breaking `free()`), and after that further lines damage your text data.